# Creating new column in pandas dataframe with a list of values from another column without using "groupby"

Tags: python, pandas

I work with large datasets, making pandas group and groupby functions take a long time/use too much memory. I have heard some people say groupby can be slow, but am having trouble finding a better solution.

If my dataframe has 2 columns similar to:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,4], 'b':[1,1,1,1]})

a     b     
1     1     
2     1     
2     1      
4     1
```

I wish to return a list of values that match to a value in another column:

```
a     b     list_of_b
1     1        [1]
2     1        [1,1]
2     1        [1,1]
4     1        [1]
```

I currently use:

```
df_group = df.groupby('a')
df['list_of_b'] = df.apply(lambda row: df_group.get_group(row['a'])['b'].tolist(), axis=1)
```

The code above works for small stuff, but not on large dataframes ( df > 1,000,000 rows) Does anyone have a faster way to do this?

Comment: Creating a list of the values is problematic due to pandas wanting to convert this to a Series and align on index, could you try `df['list_of_b'] = df['a'].map(df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list))` for speed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest solution I can think of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,4], 'b':[1,1,1,1]})
df.join(pd.Series(df.groupby(by='a').apply(lambda x: list(x.b)), name="list_of_b"), on='a')

   a  b    list_of_b
0  1  1     [1]
1  2  1  [1, 1]
2  2  1  [1, 1]
3  4  1     [1]
```

Answer (score 0):

On a 4K row df I get the following:

```
In [29]:
df_group = df.groupby('a')
​
%timeit df.apply(lambda row: df_group.get_group(row['a'])['b'].tolist(), axis=1)
%timeit df['a'].map(df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(list))

1 loops, best of 3: 4.37 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.21 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Just doing the grouping and then joining back to the original dataframe seems to be quite a bit faster:

```
def make_lists(df):
    g = df.groupby('a')
    def list_of_b(x):
        return x.b.tolist()
    return df.set_index('a').join(
        pd.DataFrame(g.apply(list_of_b),
                     columns=['list_of_b']),
        rsuffix='_').reset_index()
```

This gives me **192ms** per loop with **1M** rows generated like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,2,4], 'b':[1,1,1,1]})
low = 1
high = 10 
size = 1000000
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(low,high,size),
                    'b':np.random.randint(low,high,size)})

make_lists(df1)
Out[155]:
    a   b   list_of_b
0   1   1   [1]
1   2   1   [1, 1]
2   2   1   [1, 1]
3   4   1   [1]
In [156]:


%%timeit
make_lists(df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 192 ms per loop
```